# ConverseJs gave error in angular js Route "Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name define"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ConverseJS with angular js. I am facing problem in routing when page route to next page then I found this error

> Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name
>   define

I am doing:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/converse.min.js"></script>

require(['converse'], function (converse){
  converse.initialize({
    allow_chat_pending_contacts:true,
    allow_contact_requests:true,
    allow_dragresize:false,
    allow_muc:false,
    allow_otr: false,
    allow_registration:false,
    auto_list_rooms: false,
    auto_subscribe: true,
    auto_join_on_invite:true,
    bosh_service_url: 'http://45.55.177.22:5280/http-bind/', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
    debug: false ,
    auto_login:true,
    jid:'jid',
    password:'123',
    hide_muc_server: true,
    message_archiving: 'always',
    i18n: locales['en'], // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
    prebind: false,
    show_controlbox_by_default: false,
    xhr_user_search: false,
    image_upload_url: '/chat/image.php'
          });
      });
```

I am used this code in my index page and I found this error

> Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name
>   define

I am also used ng-view In page with help I route the page on index page. when I copied this code and place in other page which is loading by routing then its working fine on First time page load.

After page fully load and I am click to other page link then I found same error in routing.

> Error: See almond README: incorrect module build, no module name

So please help me.
define